cron job to trigger something on a remote webserver
I have a webserver with ssh access and the possibility to enter a cron job there.
I have another second webserver, where I just can create web pages to do some work (via php) when they are called from outside.
What's the best way to automate those tasks by using a cron job on the first one?
I found python3 and webbrowser in general available on that first (cron job) web server.
When testing interactively, a text based browser pops up and requires a q(uit) command to be entered.
Before going that path any further (How to enter input to a shell script running in background ?) I'd rather ask if there's a better way to solve my problem.

You can use Selenium in Python to automate using a web interface.

While looking around, I found the answer myself:
Do not need a whole webbrowser, python urllib is all I need:
import urllib.request
requ = urllib.request.urlopen('https://myurl.org/test.htm?params=asneeded')
resp = requ.read()

The response of the remote webserver myurl.org contains the whole payload of the requested page.

Another alternative is requests, which just needed  pip install requests on the cron server
